# Restoring file system hierarchy from file

Tags: c#, .net, filesystems, performance-testing

I'm creating File Management application (in .NET) which can copy, move and delete files and directories. I want to write performance tests for it. In order to do that I need to recreate directories and files hierarchy before each test. I would like to store this hierarchy in a file, so I can keep it in repository. I don't care about content of the files as long as I can defined file size, date modified etc.

And now my question. Is there any application/framework that can help me with that? It would be awesome if it has GUI to define hierarchy (like Windows explorer), because working with text files which contain thousands of records is painful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a program that stores the filesystem in an xml format :

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Xml;
using System.Xml.Linq;
using System.IO;

namespace SAveDirectoriesXml
{
    class Program
    {
        const string FILENAME = @"c:\temp\test.xml";
        const string FOLDER = @"c:\temp";
        static XmlWriter writer = null;
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            XmlWriterSettings settings = new XmlWriterSettings();
            settings.Indent = true;

            writer = XmlWriter.Create(FILENAME, settings);
            writer.WriteStartDocument(true);

            DirectoryInfo info = new DirectoryInfo(FOLDER);
            WriteTree(info);

            writer.WriteEndDocument();
            writer.Flush();
            writer.Close();
            Console.WriteLine("Enter Return");
            Console.ReadLine();

        }
        static long WriteTree(DirectoryInfo info)
        {
            long size = 0;
            writer.WriteStartElement("Folder");
            try
            {
                writer.WriteAttributeString("name", info.Name);
                writer.WriteAttributeString("numberSubFolders", info.GetDirectories().Count().ToString());
                writer.WriteAttributeString("numberFiles", info.GetFiles().Count().ToString());
                writer.WriteAttributeString("date", info.LastWriteTime.ToString());


                foreach (DirectoryInfo childInfo in info.GetDirectories())
                {
                    size += WriteTree(childInfo);
                }

            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                string errorMsg = string.Format("Exception Folder : {0}, Error : {1}", info.FullName, ex.Message);
                Console.WriteLine(errorMsg);
                writer.WriteElementString("Error", errorMsg);
            }

            FileInfo[] fileInfo = null;
            try
            {
                fileInfo = info.GetFiles();
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                string errorMsg = string.Format("Exception FileInfo : {0}, Error : {1}", info.FullName, ex.Message);
                Console.WriteLine(errorMsg);
                writer.WriteElementString("Error",errorMsg);
            }

            if (fileInfo != null)
            {
                foreach (FileInfo finfo in fileInfo)
                {
                    try
                    {
                        writer.WriteStartElement("File");
                        writer.WriteAttributeString("name", finfo.Name);
                        writer.WriteAttributeString("size", finfo.Length.ToString());
                        writer.WriteAttributeString("date", info.LastWriteTime.ToString());
                        writer.WriteEndElement();
                        size += finfo.Length;
                    }
                    catch (Exception ex)
                    {
                        string errorMsg = string.Format("Exception File : {0}, Error : {1}", finfo.FullName, ex.Message);
                        Console.WriteLine(errorMsg);
                        writer.WriteElementString("Error", errorMsg);
                    }
                }
            }

            writer.WriteElementString("size", size.ToString());
            writer.WriteEndElement();
            return size;

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: It's not really what I was hoping for, because it solves only small part of my problem, but assuming no other response means there is nothing better available. Thanks!

Comment: You can put the strucure into the treeview(or custom dialogs) so it looks similar to a explorer.  Codeproject has a number of custom dialogs that may help.

Answer (score 0):

I may be missing some of your requirements, but what I have done in the past was simply create a zip-file (or tar, 7z, etc.) with the files and folder structure that my tests expect, and have that archive checked into our source control repository.

Then I can before each test extract that archive to a temporary folder, and point my test to it. Afterwards, simply remove the temporary folder, so that the next test can start from a clean slate again.